# Let's burninate the new iPhones [iphone-xr] [iphone-xs-max]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Unless there is a significant changes in the new iPhones related to programming, I don't think we need tags for each iPhone version.

Only two question were using those tags:

[iPhone XR / XS / XS Max CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321212/iphone-xr-xs-xs-max-css-media-queries)

[Programatically detect iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max & iPhone XR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306619/programatically-detect-iphone-xs-iphone-xs-max-iphone-xr)

---

If not burninate, they can probably be synonym of [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) or [iphonex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphonex)

Comment: This seems a little premature to me. The products haven't even shipped yet, so it's hard to say that tags for each wouldn't be appropriate. This is especially true since these phones have different resolutions and hardware from existing models. I'd rather wait until the phones have been out for at least a couple of weeks.

Comment: We do appear to have a tag for most of the iphone versions. I'm not sure if we need any of the version specific tags but there are probably cases where it does matter so I'm willing to keep them

Answer (score 25):

Let's not jump the gun here...

You know in web dev how everybody condemns browser sniffing in favor of feature detection? But sometimes browser sniffing is the only "viable" solution because [fringe browsers or fringe versions of browsers have severe bugs that break sites in ways that are impossible or extraordinarily difficult to work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e/9900331#9900331) (IE, Safari...), or even intentionally lie to feature detection to make itself seem more cutting-edge than it really is<sup>1</sup>?

Or how the web collectively freaks out [whenever a new browser engine is introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575563/conditional-css-rule-targeting-firefox-quantum)?

> Anyone who has authored HTML/CSS for a reasonable amount of time knows that browsers are not perfect and specific versions of specific browsers can have bugs that otherwise break their claims of standards-compliance, and in turn feature detection. Yes, use feature detection where possible, but there are times when it doesn't work because some feature that a browser claims to support works correctly in version 60 but breaks in 61. Chrome is much, much worse for this sort of thing than any other browser, but that doesn't mean Firefox doesn't have its own bugs to speak of.
>
> We had to deal with this once in the transition from WebKit to Blink, and a second time in the transition from Trident to EdgeHTML - is it so unreasonable to have to deal with the same thing transitioning from Gecko to Stylo?

It's a similar story here. You can't really predict how new devices may behave compared to current devices even if the on-paper specs suggest they should behave identically or run your code the same way. This is true not only of iPhones but of all hardware — I've seen questions showing code inexplicably crashing on specific variations of specific GPUs that turned out to be due to undocumented hardware and/or driver issues for example.<sup>2</sup> Questions about new devices are inevitably going to surface as soon as they're announced because the vendors don't usually go out of their way to publish comprehensive documentation preemptively answering all of our developer questions.

And that's OK. **That's why Stack Overflow exists.** Questions that turn out to be so like existing ones as to be effectively duplicates can be closed as such. Questions that warrant closer examination because, indeed, your native or web layout might look wonky on that iPhone XR because of its lower resolution despite its larger screen size compared to the iPhone XS are absolutely apt to include the device-specific tags, because that question is specific to those devices. It's for the same reason web questions have browser-specific tags sometimes.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Depending on who you ask, this is basically what other browsers supporting `-webkit` prefixes are doing, except [they have a very good reason to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891231/disable-all-webkit-prefixes-in-gecko-firefox/47891366#47891366).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>I would cite iPhone-specific examples from recent generations but I haven't actively developed for iOS in many years — maybe someone else can help.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with an issue that can 'only' be reproduced with iphone-xs and iphone-xs-max

At this time I wish I had more information, but the only constant I have at this time is the phone model.

[Why did H.264, MPEG-4 HE AAC stopped working on iphoneXS/Max?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490358/why-did-h-264-mpeg-4-he-aac-stopped-working-on-iphonexs-max)

Comment: I've recreated the tags and added them to your question for you. Make sure you've isolated this to the specific devices by e.g. ensuring your simulator and other iOS devices are running the same build of iOS 12.

Comment: Thanks, i feel like this question a s$%t post, but i'm trying to do as much information gathering as possible, i honestly didn't think it was even a possibility that it was a device specific issue. Trying to get my hands on one to repro ASAP. The odd thing is, i'm pretty surprised I haven't seen any chatter on this. It's not some exotic preset `InterlacedMode:Auto,MaxReferenceFrames:3,Level:4.1,ColorSpaceConversionMode:None,Profile:high`  I wonder if i'm in some super bizarre edge case. Makes it even more uncomfortable that both sim XS/MAX are fine